# Sorting vector of string pointers

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I'm sorry if this has already been asked somewhere, but I haven't been able to find an answer to what I'm looking for.

I have a vector of std::string pointers, that I want to sort in alphabetical order, and I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. I am using std::sort.

I wrote up a [quick program](https://pastebin.com/a3miva0d) to test out what I was trying to do (since in the actual implementation, my code is being run in a child process, so it's kind of hard to debug):

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>

bool cmpStrPtrs(std::string *a, std::string *b) {
  std::string a1 = *a;
  std::string a2 = *b;
  if(a1 == a2) return 0;
  return a1 > a2 ? 1 : -1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::vector<std::string *> vec;
  std::string *str1 = new std::string("AAAAA");
  std::string *str2 = new std::string("aaaaa");
  std::string *str3 = new std::string("xxxxx");
  std::string *str4 = new std::string("bfuen");
  std::string *str5 = new std::string("xylophone");
  vec.push_back(str1);
  vec.push_back(str2);
  vec.push_back(str3);
  vec.push_back(str4);
  vec.push_back(str5);

  std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), cmpStrPtrs);
  for(std::string *str : vec) {
    printf("%s\n", str->c_str());
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When I run this, I get this output:

```
$ ./strsort
xylophone
bfuen
xxxxx
aaaaa
AAAAA
```

This doesn't seem to be in any sort of alphabetical order at all, so I can assume that I'm either using sort() wrong or there's something wrong with my comparator function. I also tried it without a comparator function and I think that's just ordering them based on their memory locations from least to greatest, which doesn't actually change anything. I also tried using

```
bool cmpStrPtrs(std::string *a, std::string *b) {
  return a->compare(*b);
}
```

but it gave me the same result.

If it's relevant, I'm compiling with g++ using the c++17 standard.

Comment: Using `new` is non-idiomatic C++. Your comparison function is wrong too (let's start with "you're returning an `int` from a function that was supposed to return `bool`") Also see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare

Comment: I do not recommend returning -1, 0, +1 in a function marked as returning  `bool`

Comment: Are you sure you want `vector<string*>` and not just `vector<string>`? I don't see what value the extra indirection adds.

Comment: Also read about [Strict Weak Ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::string::compare` returns an `int`, not a `bool`. According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) the return value is

> negative value if *this appears before the character sequence specified by the arguments, in lexicographical order
>
> zero if both character sequences compare equivalent
>
> positive value if *this appears after the character sequence specified by the arguments, in lexicographical order **strong text**

The returned value is cast to `bool` which evaluates to `true` for all non-zero values. That means that your function returns `true` for every non-identical pair of strings.

The C++ standard actually defines `operator<` for strings so you can change your function to

```
bool cmpStrPtrs(std::string *a, std::string *b) {
    return *a < *b;
}
```

But that still leaves a big issue in your code. You absolutely do not need pointers for this. In fact, you are leaking memory right now because you neglect to `delete` them. The proper tool for this job is `std::vector<std::string>`. This has the added benefit that without the extra level of indirection, `std::sort` can implicitly call `operator<` without a helper function, leading to the following solution.

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;
vec.emplace_back("AAAAA");
vec.emplace_back("aaaaa");
vec.emplace_back("xxxxx");
vec.emplace_back("bfuen");
vec.emplace_back("xylophone");

std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

Comment: Wow, I feel like such an idiot. I can't believe I didn't notice I wasn't returning a bool. Was just kind of on autopilot from writing so many java comparison functions for my algorithms class last year. Thank you!

Comment: Also, you're right that my code has problems, but the reason I'm using string pointers rather than just strings is that the underlying structure of the application requires them to be pointers. This was just a quick example I whipped up to test out what I was trying to do, not the actual implementation. Don't worry, in the actual code, they're getting deleted.

Comment: @AndrewGraber Why does it have to be pointers? Is it just because they shouldn't be copies or is there a more restricting reason?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a lambda:

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](std::string * a, std::string * b) {
    return *a < *b;    
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Your comparison function is [meant to simulate the less-than operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) - that means it should return true if a comes before b. Your current implementation returns true if a doesn't equal b.

You have:

```
if(a1 == a2) return 0;
return a1 > a2 ? 1 : -1;
```

which should be:

```
if(a1 == a2) return false;
return a1 > a2 ? false : true;
```

or just:

```
return a1 < a2;
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::sort` expects [Strict Weak Ordering.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering) It doesn't give a crap about equals; it only cares about before and after.

The comparison function should return true if the right hand side goes before left hand side. Unfortunately in

```
bool cmpStrPtrs(std::string *a, std::string *b) {
  std::string a1 = *a;
  std::string a2 = *b;
  if(a1 == a2) return 0;
  return a1 > a2 ? 1 : -1;
}
```

`bool` is true for any value that is not 0. This means that both greater than and less than are true. This makes logical ordering pretty much impossible because greater than and less than go before.

Improvement cut 1: return `bool` based on lexicographic (alphabetical) ordering. String already implements a less than operator that does exactly what you want. Let's use it.

```
bool cmpStrPtrs(std::string *a, std::string *b) {
  std::string a1 = *a;
  std::string a2 = *b;
  return a1 < a2;
}
```

Improvement cut 2: `std::string a1 = *a;` creates a brand new string that is a copy of the original. Since you have a pointer to the original you can dereference the pointer and use the original. No need for the copy.

```
bool cmpStrPtrs(std::string *a, std::string *b) {
  return *a < *b;
}
```